# php: fbird_connect(): Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". Failed to establish a connection

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using Firebird remote to access my ERP integrated with my Ecommerce, during the day work perfectly, but after 6pm (when office close) I have problem to connect, just return if restart Firebird.

I'm using AWS host with Ubuntu 18.4 32bits.
Port 3050 openned.

Error:

```
php: fbird_connect(): Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". Failed to establish a connection.
```

Comment: `I'm using Firebird remote` - no you do not, the error text clearly says "localhost" which means you try to do local TCP connection not remote. Check the database connection string/properties in your PHP program, you do not set remote connection there

Comment: If it works fine during the day, but doesn't work outside of office hours, then I would search if there is some time-sensitive firewall or VPN rule that only gives you access during office hours. And as Arioch 'The says: you're connecting to localhost, which means it isn't remote.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel guessing over "just return if restart Firebird" it more looks like they they scheduled Firebird shutdown (maybe db/vm file backup, or explicit garbage collection, or something) but don't re-start it until morning. Might be a reasonable setup for sysadmins, but since Covid made everyone work at home and blurred office hours around the clock it might have unexpected new bottlenecks